# Carbon returning the wrong date bug

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I am manipulating my dates using the php [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) package within my Laravel app. I am having some weird results when trying to generate a date (x days in the future)

Please take a look at this code:

```
$start_date = Carbon::tomorrow('Europe/London');
$end_date = $start_date->addDays($tier->duration_days);
Log::debug('Carbon::now(): '.Carbon::now());
Log::debug('Carbon::tomorrow(Europe/London): '.Carbon::tomorrow('Europe/London'));
Log::debug('$start_date: '.$start_date);
Log::debug('$end_date: '.$end_date);
```

The code above will print out the following debug lines:

> 2017-04-17 21:46:31] local.DEBUG: Carbon::now(): 2017-04-17 21:46:31
>   [2017-04-17 21:46:31] local.DEBUG: Carbon::tomorrow(Europe/London):
>   2017-04-18 00:00:00   [2017-04-17 21:46:31] local.DEBUG: $start_date:
>   2017-05-16 00:00:00   [2017-04-17 21:46:31] local.DEBUG: $end_date:
>   2017-05-16 00:00:00

Using Carbon::tomorrow() will print out the correct dates, however using $start_time which technically uses the same function returns the wrong date.
Can someone advise what could be going wrong here?

FYI I have set Europe/London as my timezone in my `config/app.php` file.

Comment: `addDays()` modifies the Carbon object.... [Carbon addDays() but without modyfing existing instance](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/carbon-adddays-but-without-modyfing-existing-instance) `$end_date = $start_date->copy()->addDays($tier->duration_days);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$date->addDays` doesn't actually return an instance with the days added, it returns the same instance after modifying the days (which makes a great deal of difference).

Therefore, you should first copy the date into a new instance and then add the days.

```
$start_date->copy()->addDays($tier->duration_days);
```